# Allow Only Explicit Specialization of Template Class

Tags: c++, templates

I want to limit a template class to the only explicit implementations. I can do this with many functions as:

```
template<typename T>
static T getEnumFromString(const std::string& in_string) = delete; // only allow templates we define (catches them at compile time)
template<> static A getEnumFromString(const std::string& in_string);
template<> static B getEnumFromString(const std::string& in_string);
```

I have a template class, that stores enum/string in maps, where I use a `static_assert` to limit to only enums, but this is not limiting enough due to enums visible (only want those defined in enclosing class):

```
template<typename TEnum>
class kvEnumHelper {
    static_assert(std::is_enum_v<TEnum>);
public:
    std::string getStringFromEnum(const TEnum& in_enum) const;
    TEnum getEnumFromString(const std::string& in_string) const;                    
protected:
    kvEnumHelper();         
    void initialize(std::vector<EnumTextPair<TEnum>> enumInitializer);
private:
    std::map<TEnum, std::string> mapEnumToString;
    std::map<std::string, TEnum> mapStringToEnum;           
};
```

I implement explicit class for each enum, (where the enum/string pairs are defined in the constructor) e.g.:

```
class AenumHelper : public kvEnumHelper<tA> {
    using myEnum = tA;
    public:
        AenumHelper();
    };
inline static AenumHelper aEnumHelper;
```

The issue is that the static assert is insufficient, as there are many other enums in scope that do not apply here. I have tried permutations like:

```
template<typename TEnum> kvEnumHelper<TEnum> = delete;
template<typename TEnum> class kvEnumHelper<TEnum> = delete;
template<> class kvEnumHelper<> = delete;
kvEnumHelper = delete;
//
```

Is there a way, similar to the function case, to allow explicit specialization for my `kvEnumHelper<>` class?

Comment: There's nothing in C++ that can constrain a type only to a type that's defined in a particular namespace, enclosing or otherwise.  This cannot be done in C++.

Comment: True, but for template functions I can specify types explicitly and delete everything else. Allowing me to only call the functions I've explicitly specified. Want to do the same for the template class.

Comment: Yes, for template functions use can specify a fixed set of possible template parameters, and delete the others. You cannot specify, for template functions, that the parameter can be anything in a particular namespace, either.

Comment: Right, I have implemented that for template functions. I just can't get the same approach to work for class templates. I want to delete all template classes that I don't specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways how you could accomplish this.

##### 1. Explicitly list the acceptable enums

One way would be to explicitly list the acceptable enums in your `static_assert`:

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/W7PzeEYeY)

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<class T, class... Other>
constexpr bool is_same_one_of = (std::is_same_v<T, Other> || ...);

enum Enum1 {};
enum Enum2 {};
enum Enum3 {};

template<class T>
class kvEnumHelper {
    static_assert(
        is_same_one_of<T, Enum1, Enum2 /* , ... more enum types ... */>,
        "T must be either Enum1 or Enum2"
    );

    /* ... actual implementation ... */
};


kvEnumHelper<Enum1> foo1; // ok
kvEnumHelper<Enum2> foo2; // ok
kvEnumHelper<Enum3> foo3; // compile error
```

---

##### 2. Inherit implementation

Another option would be to move the actual implementation into a separate class and only make the specializations inherit from the implementation class.

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/YaKEE97vd)

```cpp
#include <type_traits> 

enum Enum1 {};
enum Enum2 {};
enum Enum3 {};

template<class T>
class kvEnumHelper {
    static_assert(
        !std::is_same_v<T, T>, // always false, but only when actually instanciated
        "Enum Class is not supported"
    );
};

template<class TEnum>
class kvEnumHelperImpl {
    /* ... actual implementation ... */
};

template<> class kvEnumHelper<Enum1> : public kvEnumHelperImpl<Enum1> {};
template<> class kvEnumHelper<Enum2> : public kvEnumHelperImpl<Enum2> {};


kvEnumHelper<Enum1> foo1; // ok
kvEnumHelper<Enum2> foo2; // ok
kvEnumHelper<Enum3> foo3; // compile error
```

---

##### 3. Using an additional trait

Yet another alternative would be to use a trait that can specialized for the enum types you would want to be usable with `kvEnumHelper`.

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/91rPoqKjs)

```cpp
template <class T>
constexpr bool allow_enum_helper = false;

enum Enum1 {};
enum Enum2 {};
enum Enum3 {};

template<class T>
class kvEnumHelper {
    static_assert(
        allow_enum_helper<T>,
        "Enum Class is not supported"
    );

    /* ... actual implementation ... */
};

template<>
constexpr bool allow_enum_helper<Enum1> = true;
template<>
constexpr bool allow_enum_helper<Enum2> = true;


kvEnumHelper<Enum1> foo1; // ok
kvEnumHelper<Enum2> foo2; // ok
kvEnumHelper<Enum3> foo3; // compile error
```

If you already have a function like `getEnumFromString` that is deleted and has specializations for the allowable enum types you could use that to detect if `kvEnumHelper<T>` should be allowed by detecting if the function is deleted or not.

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/5fTW76hzP)

```cpp
#include <string>

enum Enum1 {};
enum Enum2 {};
enum Enum3 {};

template<typename T>
T getEnumFromString(const std::string& in_string) = delete; // only allow templates we define (catches them at compile time)
template<> Enum1 getEnumFromString(const std::string& in_string);
template<> Enum2 getEnumFromString(const std::string& in_string);

template<class T>
constexpr bool allow_enum_helper = requires { getEnumFromString<T>(std::string{}); };


template<class T>
class kvEnumHelper {
    static_assert(
        allow_enum_helper<T>,
        "Enum Class is not supported"
    );

    /* ... actual implementation ... */
};

kvEnumHelper<Enum1> foo1; // ok
kvEnumHelper<Enum2> foo2; // ok
kvEnumHelper<Enum3> foo3; // compile error
```

Comment: `static_assert(!std::is_same_v<T, T>)` is equivalent to `static_assert(false)` (even if compiler don't succeed to spot it) making the template ill-formed NDR, `templlate <typename> constexpr always_false = false;` or equivalent would be fine (it could be specialized for a dummy type so it would exist a valid type for your template).

Answer (score 1):

> I want to limit a template class to the only explicit implementations.

Not sure to understand exactly what you want,
for functions case, template don't provide code, and each specialization has to provide its own.

A nearly equivalent for class would be declaration without definition:

```
template <typename E>
requires(std::is_enum_v<E>) // C++20 contraint
class kvEnumHelper;

template<>
class kvEnumHelper<ta> {
    static_assert(std::is_enum_v<ta>);
public:
    std::string getStringFromEnum(const ta& in_enum) const;
    ta getEnumFromString(const std::string& in_string) const;                    
protected:
    kvEnumHelper();         
    void initialize(std::vector<EnumTextPair<ta>> enumInitializer);
private:
    std::map<ta, std::string> mapEnumToString;
    std::map<std::string, ta> mapStringToEnum;           
};
```

> `static_assert` is insufficient, as there are many other enums in scope that do not apply here

You might still be more specific in your `static_assert`, as listing the allowed enum types.